# How are players matched in multiplayer, after difficulty selection?

Tags: diablo-iii

- Is character and Paragon level taken into account?
- Can only players in the same [region](https://us.battle.net/support/en/article/global-play) (Americas, Europe, Asia) play together?
- Does equipment or stats have an effect?
- Does class play a role?

Answer (score 4):

I have no official information, but this is what I know from my own experience:

- Character level is taken into account and it will match you with similarly leveled players, or if you are level 70, it will match you with other level 70 players only.
- Paragon level is not taken into account.
- Equipment or stats have no effect on matchmaking.
- Only players playing in the same region (regardless of their physical location) will be matched together.

As long as there are players on a certain difficulty, you can be matched with them.

Comment: I understand that characters at the maximum level are only matched together, but does this apply to all levels? If it does, characters below 60 (and under 70 in general) will have *severe* issues in finding company.

Comment: I didn't say it specifically, but I thought I implied it. Under max level, there is a range of levels that can be matched together, but I do not know the exact range.

Comment: I've updated my question, see the last bullet point "Does class play a role?".

Comment: @user598527 class does not play any roll. what does play a roll is the difficulty you search for. meaning if you search t13 you will only be matched with other players searching t13

Comment: Like @XtremeBaumer said - the difficulty (and level, to an extent) are the only things that matter in matchmaking.

Comment: I was playing a level 20 yesterday when a level 1 joined, so at least at low levels, the range is very high.